# Tomcat 8 + MySQL + Spring + JPA - Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'

Tags: java, mysql, spring, tomcat, jpa

I know this question has been asked multiple times before and so I apologise for asking again, however, I have tried all the other suggested fixes and still cannot get this to work.

I am trying to create a simple web app that uses MySQL database, Tomcat 8, JNDI Datasource, Spring and JPA but I get the following error on deployment:

```
Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2049)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1939)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1412)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:96)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:444)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
```

Here is my configuration:

**content.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
  <Resource 
    name="jdbc/testapp" 
    auth="Container" 
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxTotal="100" 
    maxIdle="30" 
    maxWaitMillis="10000"
    username="test" 
    password="password123" 
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>  
</Context>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.1"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="org.iainadams.testappdb" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <description>Default MySQL database</description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/testapp</jta-data-source>
         <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
      </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

 </persistence>
```

**web.xml**

```
....
<resource-ref>
    <description>MySQL Database</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/testapp</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
....
```

**org.iainadams.testapp**

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="org.iainadams.testapp" )
@EnableJpaRepositories("org.iainadams.testapp.repositories")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer(){
        TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();
        tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions("/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles-defs.xml");
        return tilesConfigurer;
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesViewResolver viewResolver(){
        return new TilesViewResolver();
    }

    @Bean(name="entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
        LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean localEntityManagerFactory = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        localEntityManagerFactory.setPersistenceUnitName("org.iainadams.testappdb");
        return localEntityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource datasource(){
        JndiObjectFactoryBean datasourceLookup = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        datasourceLookup.setResourceRef(true);
        datasourceLookup.setJndiName("java:comp/env/jdbc/testapp");
        return (DataSource) datasourceLookup.getObject();
    }


    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager txManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return txManager;
    }

}
```

In addition, I have put my MySQL driver jar file (mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar) into the apache-tomcat-8.0.18\lib folder.

[image: Tomcat Lib]

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I would say that the file _content.xml_ is not found, since you have defined the properties there. Do you perhaps get some warning before the actual exception?

Comment: No warning. Although I did realise that it was being deployed to /WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/ along with the persistence.xml. I read that it needs to be under /META-INF directly. So I have updated my project config. However, it still doesn't deploy properly. I still get the same error.

Comment: Okay.... some progress.... If I put the <resource> description from my context.xml in the global context.xml (under $CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml) then it works. I think you are right in that my context.xml is not being recognised by the server.

Comment: Also, this works if I do not put it in the webapps directory in tomcat. If I run it from a different directory it loads fine. Any ideas on why the webapps folder wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

a) it should be java:/comp/env/jdbc/testapp (missing slash after java)

b) I believe it has to be  as tomcat does not provides jta transactions (correct me if I am wrong)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this following java config

```
@Bean
public BasicDataSource dataSource(){
       BasicDataSource basicDataSource=new BasicDataSource();
       basicDataSource.addConnectionProperty("destroy-method","close");
       basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       basicDataSource.setUsername("root");
       basicDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname");
       basicDataSource.setPassword("");
       return basicDataSource;
}

@Bean
public AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean(){
       AnnotationSessionFactoryBean asfb=new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();
       asfb.setDataSource(dataSource());
       asfb.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("hibernate.cfg.xml"));
       asfb.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

       return asfb;
}
public SessionFactory sessionFactory(){
      return sessionFactoryBean().getObject();
}
private Properties hibernateProperties(){
       Properties properties=new Properties();
       properties.put("dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");

       return properties;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @LynAs. This is really helpful as a fall back although I am keen to use JPA and JNDI if I can get it working.

Comment: There is no problem using jpa and jndi. I gave you the java config so the that you can debug better. change the driver and dialect and it will work with you jndi